# Network unreachable

Tags: networking, arch-linux

Just did a fresh Arch install but when I `ping 8.8.8.8` it says `connect : Network is unreachable`. I saved iptales rules in /etc/iptables/iptables.conf but they won't load at startup. `ip a` says that my interface `enp5s0` state is DOWN.

Any idea how to fix this ? During the install from the USB stick I wasn't able to put a hostname because `hostnamectl` was saying that dbus was unavailable or something to that extent.

Do you have an idea on how to repair my internet in fresh Arch install ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have correct device name. So change your interface name - if you've changed it to eth0 during installation - to enp5s0 in:

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd@.service`

Then you'll be able to **enable** it. You can **bring your interface up** by running :

`ip link set dev enp5s0 up`

and then **obtain an IP from DHCP** by running :

`dhcpcd enp5s0`

you can also enable dhcp@enp5s0.service by running :

`systemctl enable dhcpcd@enp5s0.service`

**N.B.** Your device name may be different, so check it first, and use all the commands above with the correct name of your interface.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it says `dhcpd: command not found`

Comment: How about the second option? Enabling it via systemctl, does it work?

Comment: @ChiseledAbs By the way, I think it was my typo mistake, the command itself is dhcpcd not dhcpd! I'm afraid mate. DHCPD is the Daemon, not the command.

Comment: `dhcpcd enp5s0` worked fine and repaired the connection, do you know how I do to not to type this every boot ?

Comment: @ChiseledAbs Find your `rc.conf` and tell me what is inside it about your interfaces.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs In fact what you should do, is to set it up for on boot time, and also set DHCPD on so it will obtain IP address itself, or you can give it a static IP Address if you like so.